# CSS selector for first instance of child with class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there a CSS selector for the first instance of a child with class? For example, take this code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="nothing">
    </div>
    <div class="child"> <!-- SELECT THIS ONE -->
    </div>
    <div class="child"> <!-- NOT THIS ONE -->
    </div>
    <div class="child"> <!-- NOT THIS ONE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a css selector to style the first occurrence of a div with class "child"?

Comment: There isn't a CSS selector, but there is a jQuery selector.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you had a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/, which lists all the selectors that jQuery understands? Personally, I would just use `$('.child').first()`.

Comment: No, there is no such selector using CSS. The closest thing is the `:first-of-type` selector, but that only matches by tag name, not class

Comment: Doh - that's unfortunate. thanks for the responses

Comment: If you're looking for a CSS solution, then this is a duplicate. You can't do this with a single selector but there is a workaround that you might be able to use. See the link.

Comment: `#container > div:nth-child(2){}` . But some properties won't be visible for empty DIV, try your browser development Inspector and find 'Copy Selector', for chrome its F12

Answer (score 9):

You could style `.child` and revert styles for subsequent `.child` siblings using the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), `~`:

```css
.child {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.child ~ .child {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="nothing">nothing
  </div>
  <div class="child">SELECT THIS ONE
  </div>
  <div class="child">NOT THIS ONE
  </div>
  <div class="child">NOT THIS ONE
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or even better reset the color to inherit and it will return to default!

Answer (score -2):

You can use the ":nth-child" css selector.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2pyvz/

CSS:

```
.child:nth-child(2) { color:red; }
```

Comment: Doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/Pex2R. Reason: `:first-child` selects the element *if and only if* it is the first child of its parent. In the OP's example, `div.nothing` is the first child though.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work for me either

Comment: I updated the answer. Like previously mentioned `:first-child` only works on the first child of the its parent. See if `:nth-child` works for you.

Comment: `.child:nth-child(2)` selects the second child of its parent, not the first `.child` element. While it might work in this specific situation, it is not a solution to actual question.

Comment: `:nth-of-type` will only select the nth of the same type of element. Being that in the example given the first child is a div element you can't use `:nth-of-type` to select the first one.